# Using checkbox in nested listview. Parent checkbox selects all child checkbox using JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, listview, checkbox

I have a nested listview with checkbox in the parent and child elements. I want to write a jquery to select all the child checkbox when parent checkbox is selected and when all the child checkbox are selected individually, the parent checkbox should be selected. I am unable to find the child element name using JQuery. It gives me the elementId of the last List binded.
Here is the code snippet:

```
<div id="div1">
    <asp:UpdatePanel runat="server" ID="upQuestionGroup">
        <ContentTemplate>

            <asp:ListView ID="lvGroup" runat="server" DataKeyNames="ID">

                <LayoutTemplate>
                    <table ID="tableGroupList">
                        <tr>
                            <th>Choose Questions</th>
                        </tr>
                        <tr runat="server" id="itemPlaceholder"></tr>
                    </table>
                </LayoutTemplate>

                <ItemTemplate>
                    <tr id="QuestionGroupName">
                        <asp:Label runat="server" ID="lblGroupId" Text='<%#Eval("ID") %>' Visible="false"></asp:Label>
                        <td>
                            <asp:Label runat="server" ID="lblQuestionGroup" Text='<%#Eval("Name")%>' />
                        </td>
                        <td>
                           <asp:CheckBox runat="server" ID="chkCrcAuditGroup" onclick="javascript:ChkAllItems(this);" />
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr id="tableQuestion">
                        <td>
                            <div id="QuestionList">
                                <asp:UpdatePanel runat="server" ID="upQuestionList">
                                    <ContentTemplate>
                                        <asp:ListView ID="lvQuestionList" runat="server" DataKeyNames="ID">
                                            <LayoutTemplate>
                                                <table ID="tableQuestionList">
                                                    <tr runat="server" id="itemPlaceholder"></tr>
                                                </table>
                                            </LayoutTemplate>

                                            <ItemTemplate>

                                                <tr>
                                                    <td>
                                                        <asp:Label runat="server" ID="lblQuestion" Text='<%#eval("question")%>'></asp:Label>
                                                    </td>
                                                    <td>
                                                        <input runat="server" id="chkSelectQuestion" type="checkbox" value='<%#Eval("ID")%>' />
                                                    </td>
                                                </tr>

                                            </ItemTemplate>

                                        </asp:ListView>

                                    </ContentTemplate>
                                </asp:UpdatePanel>
                            </div>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                </ItemTemplate>

            </asp:ListView>

        </ContentTemplate>
    </asp:UpdatePanel>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

**Try This Code**

- JavaScript

`function ChkAllItems() {
            var grdControl = document.getElementById('lvQuestionList');
            var GrdInputs = grdControl.getElementsByTagName("input");
            var ChkAll = document.getElementById('<%=chkCrcAuditGroup.ClientID%>');
            for (var i = 0; i < GrdInputs.length; ++i) {
                if (ChkAll.checked == true) {
                    GrdInputs[i].checked = true;
                }
                else {
                    GrdInputs[i].checked = false;
                }
            }
        }`

Answer (score 0):

```
$('.yourClass').click(function(){
                $('input[type=checkbox]').click(function () {
                    // children checkboxes depend on current checkbox
                    $(this).next().find('input[type=checkbox]').prop('checked',this.checked);
                    // go up the hierarchy - and check/uncheck depending on number of children checked/unchecked
                    $(this).parents('ul').prev('input[type=checkbox]').prop('checked',function(){
                        return $(this).next().find(':checked').length;
                    })
                });
            });
```

Comment: This would be a much better answer if you included more than just a code dump: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer